# make my export Excel method public and call it from other classes C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I make button_click event for export data from gridview in c# winforms to excel spreadsheet
as following

```
        private void copyAlltoClipboard()
        {
            myGridView.SelectAll();
            DataObject dataObj = myGridView.GetClipboardContent();
            if (dataObj != null)
                Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj);
        }

        private void btnExportExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            copyAlltoClipboard();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            xlexcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            xlexcel.Visible = true;
            xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range CR = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
            CR.Select();
            xlWorkSheet.PasteSpecial(CR, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);
            Clipboard.SetDataObject("");
        }
```

the problem that i repeat them so much in every view
how i can make this two mmthods public and just call them
and there is only one variable which is ***myGridView***
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you change the accessibility of the method and make any local dependencies become arguments for your method.

> Making the method static can help to isolate any local dependencies

```
public static class GridHelper
{
    public static void CopyToClipboard(DataGridView gridView)
    {
        gridView.SelectAll();
        DataObject dataObj = gridView.GetClipboardContent();
        if (dataObj != null)
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj);
    }

    public static void ExportToExcel(DataGridView gridView)
    {
        CopyToClipboard(gridView);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        xlexcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        xlexcel.Visible = true;
        xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range CR = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
        CR.Select();
        xlWorkSheet.PasteSpecial(CR, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);
        Clipboard.SetDataObject("");
    }
}
```

Then you could call that like this:

```
private void btnExportExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridHelper.ExportToExcel(myGridView);
}
```

You can actually go one step further and turn these into extension methods of the `DataGridView`, just by changing the signature of the static methods so that the `DataGridView` parameter is prefixed with `this` :

```
public static void CopyToClipboard(this DataGridView gridView)
{
    ...
}
```

and

```
public static void ExportToExcel(this DataGridView gridView)
{
    ...
}
```

Now the invokation is more *fluent*:

```
private void btnExportExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myGridView.ExportToExcel();
}
```